# How to convert Array<_Element> to array literal

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to use an array throughout my view controller so I declare it up top. However, I want populate this array with string elements. There is an easy way to do this with one line. I'm trying not to use a for loop.

```
var stringArray = [String]()
...
stringArray = Array(reversedWord.characters)
```

What is is not letting me do is convert Array<_elements> to an array literal.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Are you looking for `stringArray = reversedWord.characters.map { String($0) }`?

Comment: I'm looking to populate a string with characters. However, I do not know what to declare my initial array as.

Comment: Oh, in this case: `var charArray = [Character]()`, then you will be able to do `charArray = Array(reversedWord.characters)`.

Comment: Just another question, how do you convert a [Character] to a [String]

Comment: I've made an answer from my comments, and answered your last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that although there can be a `String` of one character, a single character is actually of type `Character`.

So when you declare an array of `String`s, you can't populate this array later with `Character`s.

So, make an array of `Character` types from the beginning:

```
var charArray = [Character]()
```

This way, when you'll split a String into characters, you'll be able to add these characters to the array:

```
charArray += Array(reversedWord.characters)
```

And to convert an array of `Character` to an array of `String`, you can use `map` and the `String()` initializer:

```
let stringArray = charArray.map { String($0) }
```

Here, `stringArray` will be of type `[String]`.

Comment: You don't need the first ` = [Character]()` part. You're making an empty array only to almost instantly replace it with a new onw

Comment: @AMomchilov I know. I was just imitating OP's example. But this is a good point, I'm making an edit. Thanks.

Comment: @AMomchilov Actually, no, no edit: I did this on purpose. Read the beginning of OP's question: `I want to use an array throughout my view controller so I declare it up top.` But I fixed a typo (was `=` instead of `+=` or `append`). :)

Comment: Yes, that would just be an instance variable. You're clobbering it anyway everytime you reassign to it. I think OP was just using that array to let the compiler infer the type of `charArray`. It just needs a type annotation instead.

Comment: Ok, there was a typo I just fixed, I just replaced `=` with `+=` because that was my original intent (I explain `...able to add...` to OP). No clobbering anymore. And no, I won't write just a type annotation here, because I think OP actually uses the array before this. Anyway: implementation detail related to OP's example, and doesn't contradict the explanation about `Character` != `String`, which is the heart of the answer: `when you declare an array of Strings, you can't populate this array later with Characters`. I think this is clear enough.